# Dialogueflow CX webhook validation

Tags: validation, webhooks, dialogflow-cx

Good-day

I am using Dialogue Flow CX to create a bot.
One parameter that I am collecting needs to be validated against a series of functions and therefore I will need to use the web hook functionality.
If the value is incorrect I would like to re-prompt , doing this about 3 times before I move the user on. This is very much like using no-match 1,2,3 etc.
What I cant seem to find is any documentation on how to do this.
Is there a way to send back JSON response with a no-match?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide an example of your requirement? Does this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dialogflow-cx-retail-agent#0) help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, i went through it and while a very good tutorial on setting up a agent it does not meet my need.
An example:
1. The bot asks the user to enter a pin number.
2. The bot captures this number and uses a webhook to validate if this is correct. 
3. If it is correct the Bot responds with a positive and moves on.                                  4. If it is not correct the bot should reply “This is incorrect” and allow a re-attempt
5. The user should be allowed a max of 3 re-attempts before the bot moves to the next flow: “i see your having some issues”

Comment: Can you provide a sample code which you have tried? You can refer to this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/webhook) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook) to create webhook.